# I want to have an Image show up from an event using UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

so I am getting really frustrated with Objective-C and Xcode right now haha...I'm trying to get an image pop up if the code enters and if statement, which basically checks to see if the user guessed the correct letters in the word in my game (think hang man). Once it enters the if statement, I want to have an image pop up stating something like "Congrats! you got 50 points!" and then move to the next word in the game...

so the code looks something like this:

```
if (isWordCompleted)
{
    //do some code that has the pop up image
    //other stuff as well
}
```

I've looked all over stackoverflow and can't seem to get the answer I'm looking for :S

EDIT:

```
if(isWordComplete)
    {

        //create an image reference to have pop up congratulating the user for guessing the right answer
        UIImage *congratsImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Congrats.png"];
        UIImageView *congratsImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:congratsImage];

        [congratsImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 158)];
        [myDisplay setHidden:YES];
        [myDisplay2 setHidden:YES];
        [myDisplay3 setHidden:YES];
        [myDisplay4 setHidden:YES];
        [myDisplay5 setHidden:YES];
        [myDisplay6 setHidden:YES];
        [myDisplay7 setHidden:YES];
        [self checkNumberofWordsUserCompleteInLevel:isWordComplete];
        [self moveToNextWord];
}
```

Comment: In which view you are adding your 'congratsImageView'?

Answer (score 0):

When your if statement executed then in if statement open another UIView & on View put an

ImageView & also put your image in ImageView. Or you can also try with PopupView in iPhone.

Put your image in Popupview. UIView from tools below is image:
[image]

also see image view adding image picture:
[image]

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean for the UIView...I dont wish to use popupview however

Comment: ok I see the view thing, but how do I attach an image to that? I'm sorry if these are basic questions, but I'm in a software class at uni...the teacher doesn't teach us iOS (in fact, he doesn't know much about iOS at all) he just expects us to learn...

Comment: Just add that view along with your controller & also add an imageview in that view from drag & drop from tools & also then put image in image view.

Comment: See my edit answer when you add image view on view then when you go to file inspector on click upon image view You have seen above option as I show you in image as you also add image in image view...